# Does shallow copy of the state create errors?

Tags: reactjs, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Updating a state property without copying it and using `setState()` can lead to errors as stated by [this article](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/). What I want to know is that if I have a list of objects in the state like so:

```
this.state = {
  myList: [
    {name: "Nestor"},
    {name: "Rufus"}
  ]
};
```

Would it cause errors if I just update it with a shallow copy like that:

```
let list = [...this.state.myList];
//I modify the list here
this.setState({myList: list});
```

Or I have to do a deep copy to be absolutely certain that there won't be bugs?

```
let list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.myList));
//I modify the list here
this.setState({myList: list});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A shallow copy is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your use case.

Most of the time you can get away with a shallow copy.

But if for some reason, the props (or state) you are passing needs deep comparison, then you will have to resort to libraries like `react-fast-compare`.

Using a shallow copy won't introduce any bugs, at worst some of your components will not re-render properly.

You might want to read these :

https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-fast-compare